# Putting a SQL query in a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql

I've got several queries I want to run on a single page. I obviously don't want to put the actual queries in my template file, so I *think* what I want to do is construct a function and call it wherever I want the query results to show up. Right?

So, for example,  I'll have `<?php sidebar_query()?>` in the sidebar, `<?php footer_query()?>` in the footer, etc.

So, I just make a file called `functions.php`, do PHP include, and put something like this in there?

```
<?php
    function sidebar_query(){
        $query = ("SELECT sidebarposts FROM table;");
    return $query;
}
?>
```

or do you use `echo` and not return anything?

```
<?php
    function sidebar_query(){
        $query = ("SELECT sidebarposts FROM table;");
        echo $query;
}
?>
```

Along the exact same line, I'd like to count the results that get returned, and display a 'There were X posts returned!' message below. Seems like it would make sense to put this in a function too. How would I make a 'generic' function that I could reuse for each query?

```
<?php
    function number_of_results(){
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows();
        echo $num_rows;
}
?>
```

I'd be extremely grateful if someone could give me the theoretical gist of what I should be trying to achieve here.

Thanks for helping a beginner.

Terry

Comment: read the php doc on how to run mysql queries....

Comment: FYI - docs:  `Old approach` [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), `New approaches` [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I get what you mean.

Return the value instead like this

```
    function sidebar_query(){
        $rValue = "";
        $query = ("SELECT sidebarposts FROM table;");
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $rValue = $row['sidebarposts'];
        }
    return $rValue;
    }
```

Now you can echo sidebar_query(); or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: You would need to pass the mysql connection reference variable to the function, I believe.

Comment: @Anthony, not needed, since it uses the latest opened connection anyways.

Comment: @joakimdahlstrom, not if it's the first function he's calling.

Comment: yea let's say his index.php page calls that function first and nothing else. unless the user initiated the DB parameters elsewhere, i assume it wouldn't work. I'm basing all this off his initial question where he isn't too sure of himself. that is all.

Comment: I thought it didn't have access to the connection since it was outside the function, even if it was the last open connection.  If it works it works, but I always pass in my connection variable, just for best practice sake.

Comment: Usually you always include config and some open database connection on the top of your index. Then you work this way if not oo php5 style

Comment: FYI - docs:  `Old approach` [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), `New approaches` [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 4):

By doing `("SELECT sidebarposts FROM table;")`you're not actually doing anything, you just have a string stored as a variable.

A simple example is

```
function sidebar_query()
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT title,post FROM table;"); //query the db
    $resArr = array(); //create the result array

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { //loop the rows returned from db
        $resArr[] = $row; //add row to array
    }

    return $resArr;   
}
```

Then to use it you can do

```
$sideBarPosts = sidebar_query(); //get the result array

foreach($sideBarPosts as $post) { //loop the array
    echo '<h1>'. $post['title']. '</h1>';
    echo '<p>'. $post['post']. '</p>';
}
```

---

**EDIT**. I see you want to let the function print it directly, you can do that instead of returning the array, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

```
   function sidebar_query(){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table;");
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $resArr = array(); //create the result array

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { //loop the rows returned from db
      $resArr[] = $row; //add row to array
    }
    return $resArr;   
    }
```

and that :

```
    $sideBarPosts = sidebar_query(); //get the result array

    foreach($sideBarPosts as $post) { //loop the array
      echo '<h1>'. $post['title']. '</h1>';
      echo '<p>'. $post['post']. '</p>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**// Set Connection with database**

```
$conn = mysql_pconnect($servername,$username,$password) or die("Can not Connect MySql Server!");
```

**// Select database you want to use**

```
mysql_select_db($databasename,$conn) or die("Can not select Data Base!");
```

**// When you want to query SQL inside php function, you need to pass connection($conn) to the function as below.**

```
function sidebar_query($condb)
   {
     $strSql = "SELECT sidebarposts FROM table";
     $result = mysql_query($strSql,$condb);
     return $result;
   }
```

**// Call function**

```
 sidebar_query($conn);
```

This is work for me as i use with my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Read the php doc on how to run mysql query.

`Yay` you have the query, now you need to do something with it:

`mysql_query($query);` for example might work for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to run the query and return the result in whatever format you want to use in your template.. so for the raw number you want to return an integer, for the sidebar posts return an array of posts OR the mysql result.

You should make the "'There were X posts returned!' " thing a completely different function which you can pass in an integer an an optional string. This way you can reuse it for a ton of stuff. for example:

```
function format_nb_records($nb_records, $format = 'There were %s posts returned!'){
   return sprintf($format, $nb_records);
}
```

Although in this case i dont think there is really enough extra logic to warrant wrapping it in a function. I would probably just do this directly in my template.

A good example of where something like this is useful is if you want to do "time in words" functionality like "Yesterday" or "10 minutes ago" then you would pass in the time calculate which string to use, format it and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Although in this case i dont think there is really enough extra logic to warrant wrapping it in a function. I would probably just do this directly in my template.

A good example of where something like this is useful is if you want to do "time in words" functionality like "Yesterday" or "10 minutes ago" then you would pass in the time calculate which string to use, format it

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass database connection name to function like this,

You already have a connection name, mine is $connect_name

```
$connect_name= mysql_connect( 'host', 'user', 'password');

function getname($user,$db){
    $data= mysql_query("SELECT $user...", $db);
    //your codes
    //return bla bla
}

echo getname("matasoy",$connect_name);
```

This work for me.

I also use this for [medoo.min](http://medoo.in/) sql system. You can use medoo with functions like this;

```
function randevu($tarih,$saat,$db){

    $saat_varmi = $db->count("randevu",array("AND"=>array("tarih"=>$tarih,"saat"=>$saat)));

    if($saat_varmi>0)
        return 3;
    else
        return 2;               
}
```

have a nice day, [Murat ATASOY](http://grafanimasyon.blogspot.com.tr/)